# Ansible - Define Inventory at run time

Tags: variables, roles, ansible, inventory

I am liitle new to ansible so bear with me if my questions are a bit basic.

Scenario:

I have a few group of Remote hosts such as [EPCs] [Clients] and [Testers]
I am able to configure them just the way I want them to be.

Problem:

I need to write a playbook, which when runs, asks the user for the inventory at run time.
As an example when a playbook is run the user should be prompted in the following way:
"Enter the number of EPCs you want to configure"
"Enter the number of clients you want to configure"
"Enter the number of testers you want to configure"

What should happen:

Now for instance the user enters 2,5 and 8 respectively. 
Now the playbook should only address the first 2 nodes in the group [EPCs], the first 5 nodes in group [Clients] and the first 7 nodes in the group [Testers] . 
I don't want to create a large number of sub-groups, for instance if I have 20 EPCs, then I don't want to define 20 groups for my EPCs, I want somewhat of a dynamic inventory, which should automatically configure the machines according to the user input at run time using the **vars_prompt** option or something similar to that

Let me post a partial part of my playbook for better understanding of what is to happen:

```
---
- hosts: epcs # Now this is the part where I need a lot of flexibility

  vars_prompt:
    name: "what is your name?"
    quest: "what is your quest?"

  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Check if path exists
    stat: path=/home/khan/Desktop/tobefetched/file1.txt
    register: st

  - name: It exists
    debug: msg='Path existence verified!'
    when: st.stat.exists

   - name: It doesn't exist
     debug: msg="Path does not exist"
     when: st.stat.exists == false

   - name: Copy file2 if it exists
     fetch: src=/home/khan/Desktop/tobefetched/file2.txt dest=/home/khan/Desktop/fetched/   flat=yes
     when: st.stat.exists

   - name: Run remotescript.sh and save the output of script to output.txt on the Desktop
     shell: cd /home/imran/Desktop; ./remotescript.sh > output.txt

   - name: Find and replace a word in a file placed on the remote node using variables
     shell: cd /home/imran/Desktop/tobefetched; sed -i 's/{{name}}/{{quest}}/g' file1.txt

    tags:
       - replace
```

@gli I tried your solution, I have a group in my inventory named test with two nodes in it. When I enter **0..1** I get:

```
TASK: [echo sequence] ********************************************************* 
changed: [vm2] => (item=some_prefix0)
changed: [vm1] => (item=some_prefix0)
changed: [vm1] => (item=some_prefix1)
changed: [vm2] => (item=some_prefix1)
```

Similarly when I enter **1..2** I get:

```
TASK: [echo sequence] ********************************************************* 
changed: [vm2] => (item=some_prefix1)
changed: [vm1] => (item=some_prefix1)
changed: [vm2] => (item=some_prefix2)
changed: [vm1] => (item=some_prefix2)
```

Likewise when I enter **4..5** (nodes not even present in the inventory, I get:

```
TASK: [echo sequence] ********************************************************* 
changed: [vm1] => (item=some_prefix4)
changed: [vm2] => (item=some_prefix4)
changed: [vm1] => (item=some_prefix5)
changed: [vm2] => (item=some_prefix5)
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use [vars_prompt](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_prompts.html) for getting information from user, [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/add_host_module.html) for updating hosts dynamically and [with_sequence](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html) for loops:

```
$ cat aaa.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars_prompt:
    - name: range
      prompt: Enter range of EPCs (e.g. 1..5)
      private: False
      default: "1"
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Set node id variables
      set_fact:
        start: "{{ range.split('..')[0] }}"
        stop: "{{ range.split('..')[-1] }}"
    - name: "Add hosts:"
      add_host: name="host_{{item}}" groups=just_created
      with_sequence: "start={{start}} end={{stop}} "

- hosts: just_created
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: echo sequence
      shell: echo "cmd"
```

The output will be:

$ ansible-playbook aaa.yml -i 'localhost,'

```
Enter range of EPCs (e.g. 1..5) [1]: 0..1

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

TASK: [Set node id variables] *************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [Add hosts:] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0)
ok: [localhost] => (item=1)

PLAY [just_created] ***********************************************************

TASK: [echo sequence] *********************************************************
fatal: [host_0] => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
fatal: [host_1] => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/gli/aaa.retry

host_0                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
host_1                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Here, it failed as host_0 and host_1 are unreachable, for you it'll work fine.

btw, I used more powerful concept "range of nodes". If you don't need it, it is quite simple to have "start=0" and ask only for "stop" value in the prompt.

Comment: I found something very interesting. If I call my playbook.yml inside a mainplaybook.yml and pass on the target parameter then can I specify something like the following in my playbook.yml   -hosts: localhost[{{target}}] and then increment target until I reach the users specified value. Anything like that possible ??

Comment: I didn't get it, sorry. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The code snippet you posted does not help to contain the inventory according to user input. I have simply posted the results of your code

Comment: First of all you shouldn't call playbook from playbook, you should use [roles](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html) instead. And inside the role task you can use loops. The same way as I used. So you can split one my answer into two files, one for main playbook, second (with loop) for role.

Comment: Ah, I see, you don't want to make loops for hosts, you need dynamic hosts array. Let me think a little.

Comment: had to make a a slight change'code' ---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars_prompt:
    - name: range
      prompt: Enter range of EPCs (e.g. 1..5)
      private: False
      default: "1"
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Set node id variables
      set_fact:
        start: "{{ range.split('..')[0] }}"
        stop: "{{ range.split('..')[-1] }}"
    - name: "Add hosts:"
      add_host: name="vm{{item|int +1}}" groups=just_created
      with_sequence: "start={{start}} end={{stop}} "

- hosts: just_created
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: echo sequence
      shell: echo "cmd"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can define an inventory at run time. One thing you can do is, write a wrapper script over Ansible which will first prompt user for the hosts and then dynamically structure an ansible-playbook command.

I would prefer doing this using python, but you can use any language of your choice.

```
$ cat ansible_wrapper.py 
import ConfigParser
import os

nodes = ''
inv = {}

hosts =  raw_input("Enter hosts: ")
hosts = hosts.split(",")

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.readfp(open('hosts'))
sections = config.sections()

for i in range(len(sections)):
    inv[sections[i]] = hosts[i]


for key, value in inv.items():
    for i in range(int(value)):
        nodes = nodes + config.items(key)[i][0] + ";"


command = 'ansible-playbook -i hosts myplaybook.yml -e "nodes=%s"' % (nodes)
print "Running command: ", command
os.system(command)
```

Note: I've tried running this script only using python2.7

Comment: Thank You Ramesh, but I need something built into ansible working for me, as I have to pass the playbook(s) on to someone